# Pod file in framework

Tags: xcode, git, git-submodules, cocoapods

We are working on many projects having common basic functionality, so we decided to put the common functionality in a framework and use it as git submodule, All well and good.

Now, I want to control Pods from framework as well, so I tried to put the Podfile into framework.
As Podfile and .xcodeproj are not in same directory, so to link the xcodeproj I tried to put

```
xcodeproj '../XYZ.xcodeproj'
```

As XYZ is different for every project, so want to use something like this.

```
xcodeproj '../*.xcodeproj'
```

Is there any way I can do it?

BTW it may be possible if I create a Private Pod and then use the Pods as dependencies of it, But in my case above solution will be handy.